# creating a user input "spreadsheet" by use of form

Tags: javascript, html, html-table

I've created the following:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<body>
<h1>Budget Input</h1><br>

      <label for="category">Category:</label>
      <input type="text" name="category" id="category">

      <label for="amount">Amount:</label>
      <input type="currency" name="amount" id="amount" value="$">

      <label for="frequency">Frequency: </label>
        <select id="frequency" name="frequency">
          <option value="weekly">Weekly</option>
          <option value="fortnightly">Fortnightly</option>
          <option value="monthly">Monthly</option>
        </select>
        <button id="submit" onclick="submit()">Save</button>
    </form>
    <br>
      <hr>
      <h1>My Budget</h1>
    <table id="output">
     <thead>
      <tr>
        <th id="heading"><b>Category</b></th>
        <th id="heading"><b>Amount</b></th>
        <th id="heading"><b>Frequency</b></th>
      </tr>
      </thead>
      <tr>
        <td id="outText"><span id="categoryResult"></span></td>
        <td id="outText"><span id="amountResult"></span> </td>
        <td id="outText"><span id="optionResult"></span></td>
      </tr>
    </table>
    </span>
 </body>
```

function submit() {

        var strText = document.getElementById("category").value;          
        var strText1 = document.getElementById("amount").value;
        var strText2 = document.getElementById("frequency").value;
        var result1 = strText;
        var result2 = strText1;
        var result3 = strText2;
        document.getElementById('categoryResult').textContent = result1;
        document.getElementById('amountResult').textContent = result2;
        document.getElementById('optionResult').textContent = result3;
   }

It's working the way that I want. User inputs data in the "category, amount, option" fields and hits "save" button and the data is put below.
However I want the user to be able to submit multiple rows of data.
How do I make this happen? Currently inputting new data overrides the first input. If that makes sense. (New to coding in general)

Comment: You've to create new rows and cells to the table, see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLTableElement . Notice also, that [id](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/id)s within the document are supposed to be unique. After you've read how tables work, you'll find out that you don't need those ids at all.

Answer (score 0):

```
function submit() {
    var strText = document.getElementById("category").value;          
    var strText1 = document.getElementById("amount").value;
    var strText2 = document.getElementById("frequency").value;
    var result1 = strText;
    var result2 = strText1;
    var result3 = strText2;
    document.getElementById('categoryResult').textContent = result1;
    document.getElementById('amountResult').textContent = result2;
    document.getElementById('optionResult').textContent = result3;
}
```

Comment: Because you're circumventing the rules, there's too much code compared to the bread text in the question. Please don't use answers to add details to your question, [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/72674743/edit) the question instead.